# Swift is not available for OS X Application?

Tags: macos, swift

I just had a clean install of Yosemite Version 10.10 (14A389), and my Xcode is Version 6.0.1 (6A317). When I create a new iOS project, I can choose languages from Swift and Objective-C. However, when I create a new OS X project, the only option of languages is Object-C. Swift seems to be missing from the OS X Applications. So does Swift only work on iOS, not OS X, or am I missing something and I have to do something to enable it?

Thanks,
Elgs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift for OS X comes in Xcode 6.1. It has not been released outside the developer program yet, as the 6.1 build comes with the 8.1 SDK. I expect that it will come with the iOS 8.1 release on Monday.